# What do these codes mean?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to understand this code, but I can't really make any sense of it. I only understand the `var numbers`  and `var operators`.

What does the code inside the while loop mean? Especially the
`number[divide] / numbers[divide + 1]`

```js
var numbers   = inputString.split(/\+|\-|\×|\÷/g);
var operators = inputString.replace(/[0-9]|\./g, "").split("");

resultBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

  var divide = operators.indexOf("÷");
  while (divide != -1) {
    numbers.splice(divide, 2, numbers[divide] / numbers[divide + 1]);
    operators.splice(divide, 1);
    divide = operators.indexOf("÷");
  }
)}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 1):

> var divide = operators.indexOf("÷");

The code above returns the index of the ÷ symbol, if one is not found, then it returns -1.

The condition in the while loop basically checks if there are still "÷" symbols (since if it is -1, it would mean none are found).

> numbers.splice(divide, 2, numbers[divide] / numbers[divide + 1]);

The code above removes 2 elements at the index of the division sign. In other words, it deletes the dividend and divisor.

The third parameter of the splice function calculates the quotient and places it at the index of the division sign.

Essentially, the code deletes the dividend and divisor and then replaces it with the quotient.

> "operators.splice(divide, 1)"

removes the operator which in this case is "÷".

Finally,

> "divide = operators.indexOf("÷")"

finds the next division sign, and if none is found, "divide" would equal -1, and the code exits the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is splitting the numbers into an array using operators as split points

```js
var numbers = inputString.split(/\+|\-|\×|\÷/g);
```

This is splitting the operators in to an array now

```
var operators = inputString.replace(/[0-9]|\./g, "").split("");
```

This is an event lister on a result button being clicked.

```
resultBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {});
```

```js
let inputString = '15÷3'
var numbers = inputString.split(/\+|\-|\×|\÷/g);
var operators = inputString.replace(/[0-9]|\./g, "").split("");

// Looking for the index num for divide operator in operators array
var divide = operators.indexOf('÷');
// While loop asking if divide operator is in list of operators taken from string
// Run this function

const runLoop = () => {
  while (divide != -1) {
    // This is splicing start at index of divide, replace next 2 in array and leave result of divided answer
    numbers.splice(divide, 2, numbers[divide] / numbers[divide + 1]);
    console.log(numbers)
    // testing if there is another divide operator and removing it if found
    operators.splice(divide, 1);
    console.log(divide)
    console.log(numbers)
    // Resets divide operator location for while loop
    divide = operators.indexOf('÷');
  }
  // I added this for examle
  return numbers;
}

const Result = runLoop();
console.log(Result);
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(Result, null, '\t'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```